# jQuery to hide dummy button and show submit button

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have this js (jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    if ($('input.checkbox_check').is(':checked')) {
        $('#hide-temp-submit').hide();
        $('#show-submit').show();
    }
</script>
```

And this HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_check" name="" value="">
<button class="login_button" id='hide-temp-submit' style="background-color:#101010;color:grey;">Please Agree to Terms</button>
<button class="login_button" id='create_button show-submit' style="display:none">Create Account</button>
```

Any help on hiding the 'dummy' submit button, and showing the actual submit button once the checkbox is checked?

Thank you!

Comment: Does the temp button perform any function? If not, why not label your checkbox? Then you could either check on the form submit if the checkbox is checked or have the real button disabled by default then enable it when the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use classes--you've got a space in your second buttons ID:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    if ($('input.checkbox_check').is(':checked')) {
        $('.hide-temp-submit').hide();
        $('.show-submit').show();
    }
</script>
```

Html:

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_check" name="" value="">
 <button class="login_button hide-temp-submit"  style="background-color:#101010;color:grey;">Please Agree to Terms</button>
 <button class="login_button create_button show-submit"  style="display:none">Create Account</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is mostly correct, but you don't have it called on a specific event, only when the page loads.

You just have to wire an event to the checkbox change, and as mentioned above, your ID is invalid for your submit button.

```js
$(".checkbox_check").on("change", function() {
  if ($('input.checkbox_check').is(':checked')) {
    $('#hide-temp-submit').hide();
    $('#show-submit').show();
  } else {
    $('#hide-temp-submit').show();
    $('#show-submit').hide();    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_check" name="" value="">
<button class="login_button" id='hide-temp-submit' style="background-color:#101010;color:grey;">Please Agree to Terms</button>
<button class="login_button" id='show-submit' style="display:none">Create Account</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only run when page loads, you need an event handler to manage user input

```
$(function(){    
    $('input.checkbox_check').change(function(){
        $('#hide-temp-submit').toggle(!this.checked);
        $('#show-submit').toggle(this.checked);
    }).change(); // trigger event on page load (if applicable)   
});
```

`toggle( boolean)` will hide/show

Note: You have an invalid space separated ID on the `show-submit` button

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q5p91c8a/)**</kbd>